# Server of maps in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, geocode

I was informed that it is possible to write addresses in PostgreSQL,
where only by providing the database with the geographical coordinates of a point, I get the name and number of the street, city, state, country and even the ZIP code through PostgreSQL intelligence.

I would like to know if there is already a complete base to install in my PostgreSql, free or paid, to get addresses based on the coordinates I inform.

Or if there is any article taught to create my own map server.

Comment: https://www.openstreetmap.org

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but this isn't quite the right place for this question, because it's a bit broad, and the [help] mentions some reasons why "recommendation" questions don't fit the site's format. However, you might be interested to look at existing questions on the https://gis.stackexchange.com site; in general, "GIS" is the term you will want to read up on.

Comment: the term is "reverse geocoding"